# switching from assembly to C in embedded systems

Tags: c, assembly, embedded

I need some advice to get an idea about developping programs in C for microcontrollers. I already developed programs in assembly for microcontroller atmega in assembly. I can say that I have some experience, since I developed some drivers for sensors, motors servors, SD-card, and so on.

Now I am trying to develop programs in C for microcontrollers. I have some experience in C but only on linux-based-computer (PC). When I tried to develop some programs in C for  a special microcontroller, I get confused. I don ´t know, which approach I should follow when I write code.  When I write code in assembly, I always read the datasheet of microncontrollers. I take care about all registers, so I can use them correctly. But when I use functions in C, I use them without knowing which registers are used by this function.

**The first question Q1**:

Do I need to understand the content of functions that I may use in my program??

**the second question Q2**:

when I begin to write a program in c for a microcontroller. What are the first steps that I should do?

(1) should I begin with reading the datasheet ?

(2) should I firstly look for the methods integrated in libraries of the microcontroller that I can use for my program and begin to write it. When I need something more accurate, then I can take a look on the datasheet

I don´t want to waste time like I do with assemby. I think that second approach is better then the first one. Any Suggestion from embedded software professionals?

Comment: Well if the compiler does the register allocation for you, all you can do is trust it. Or distrust it. (sorry, I cannot see your problem)

Comment: You are somehow abke to program in C for a PC without knowing all the underlying hardware inside and out. Why a microcontroller should be any different?

Comment: As far as CPU registers go, they're managed by the compiler as joop says, and you don't have to worry about them unless you're also writing assembly language code that interfaces with your C. In that case you would need to learn your target's calling convention. As far as device registers go you generally assume that function you're calling knows what they're doing with them. They should document any side effects that they might have on the device state.

Comment: Even @ x86, when looking at generated assembly, I am often amazed by the register choices. But it all seems to work. (IMHO x86 is more and more towards RISC: less special-purpose registers, more general purpose registers.) But once you forget about AL,BX, CX, AX:DX, ES:DI and DS:DI, etc you get used to it.

Comment: @joop: Universal registers is not a RISC-feature - see 32000, 680x0, etc. OTOH Transputer was RISC with only three registers. x86 in no way is getting nearer to RISC at the application level.

Comment: My statement was not intended to be absolute. But the *tendency* for more general purpose registers (or: register *use*)  ,and less special purpose, is noticible, even for CICS. (for example: the usage of SI&DI is very different from -say- 20 years ago. This could be caused by reg<->>reg swaps being cheap (registers are basically aliasses for stuff inside a registerbank, IIUC)

Comment: @joop: (Please learn to use the `@`). You are just refering to x86, the best example how long one can ride a dead horse. There is no other 32 bit+ architecture which has/had to stock up the register banks or make them universal (and with x64 they changed the instruction and register set to a more uniform/orthogonal one. Simply because these were designed properly from scratch. Just have a look at 680x0, MIPS, PPC, PDP-11/MicroVAX, etc.

Comment: @n.m When you program in c for  a PC, you can choose between dynamic or static memory allcotion. Perhaps when you use structures, you must take care of  structure padding. You don´t care about registers.... So when you program on microcontroller yu should take care of that. So you cannot use methods without knowing which register it uses and so  on. I mean, when you program on microcontroller, you take care of small things. So it is different then programming on PC

Comment: You say "you should not do that for a PC but you should do that for a uC", but you are not providing any justification for your opinion. Which just might be, you know, not entirely correct.

Answer (score 4):

When you write in C for a microcontroller, you can stop worrying about "small things", such as CPU register allocation and stack management, and spend your time developing the functionality that you need to deliver. Naturally, this comes at the price of delegating *some* control to your compiler. However, this is usually a very good trade-off, because register and stack tracking can be done by computer to achieve a greater or equal efficiency to what can be done manually. Computer also eliminates silly but hard-to-find bugs a human can introduce while managing register allocation manually.

This does not mean, however, that you can forget about the datasheet for your microcontroller: things like managing ISRs and I/O pins are still your responsibility. It may be a good idea to check the code the compiler generated for your ISR to make sure there are no surprises there, or even to code your ISRs in assembly.

Comment: Actually the first part should be taken to a somewhat limited extent as well.

Comment: As a side note, the documentation of the compiler becomes as important as the microcontroller datasheet. This is the documentation that will tell you if the compiler diverges from the standard C language and how much. For instance 8-bit pic have no stack but the compiler still allow function calls (non-reentrant though). The documentation will also tell you  **how** to access important ports and registers (or even have a function for that).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Assuming that you trust your compiler, I found that it is OK to stop worrying about purely mechanical things that I must keep in the back of my mind while coding in assembly. When I switched to C from assembly for microcontrollers (which happened for me some 20 years ago) I used to double-check disassembly while running my code, but as I learned to trust my compiler more and more, I eventually switched to source-level debugging, with very little disassembly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is not exactly what I was talking about. You still need to know your memory architecture to write the correct linker script. You still need to write a startup code to allocate the stack, to initialise the "initialised" `.data` section and so on. Some of these tasks require understanding of the target C compiler in addition to the HW architecture. Of course, sometimes the HW vendors are trying to make these steps transparent. But it is not the case pretty often.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave normal register allocation for compiler. but of course there is some situations where you must place a variable or a function in fixed place in ROM and you could use linker script for this. Also for a microcontroller which has a small memory size many problem may happen like stack overflow or defragmentations, i think the debugger could help you in this step.

You cannot leave the datasheet, i develop in c for AVR and always look at the datasheet. and you will use it alot if you want to create the driver library yourself not include other library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend time understanding C. Know about `volatile`, memory barriers, why NULL and not 0, why casting should be avoided, how structures are packed in memory, and their little and big-endian, packed or not differences, and perhaps what the stack looks like during a function call, how floating point args are passed in your architecture, how static variables in functions might work, when to use const in a declaration, and what the many, many compiler flags do, etc. Start with flag `-Wall`.